# Using PHP to print to a shared windows printer (Linux PHP Server)

Tags: php, linux, printing

I have a printer hooked up to a windows computer (printer is shared).  Is there any way I can have my PHP server which is on the network call that windows printer to print?

Currently I use Connectship to print to these printers but I was wondering if I could write something in PHP to print

Comment: PHP has no printer support. Anything you do would have to be an external thing. Look into using CUPS, or IPP

Answer (score -2):

I believe there is: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php

printer_open — Opens a connection to a printer

Comment: @JohndaveDecano You'd *think* so, but... "Windows Only Extensions".